# Angular 2 setting background image and color in [ngStyle]

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am working on an Angular 2 project and trying to set both a background image and a opaque gradient using `[ngStyle]` These will eventually be variables pulled from JSON, or else I would just write them in my SCSS file. This is the code I am trying to use but it's not working.  I can set either a background color or image using `[ngStyle]`, but not both.

```
<header [ngStyle]="{
    'background': 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(119, 233, 207, 0.5), 
     rgba(119, 233, 207, 0.5)), 
     url('example.com/image.png') center center / cover no-repeat'
}">
```

This code in my SCSS file gives me exactly the result I want.

```
header {        
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(119, 233, 207, 0.5), 
    rgba(119, 233, 207, 0.5)), 
    url('example.com/img.png');
}
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to specify both a background image and a opaque gradient using `[ngStyle]`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you're having stems from the usage of single-quotes (`'`) in the `url()` property.  *(Honestly, I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error.)*

Removing them displays your desired result:

**For Example:**

```
<header [ngStyle]="{
  'background': 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(119, 233, 207, 0.5), 
                rgba(119, 233, 207, 0.5)), 
                url(example.com/img.png) center center / cover no-repeat'}">
```

**[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Z74eKmVDpyYYwTIPgLQ?p=preview)**

Unfortunately, the standard escape (`\'`) does not seem to work in this context, but removing the single-quotes entirely is valid as well (assuming the value used for `url()` is URL-Encoded).